# How To: Regular Expression Starting With Number/Letter between 2 and 150 length

Tags: c#, regex

I have been learning regular expressions and having some trouble coming up with a pattern.

The requirements are that it must start with a letter, number, # or @. 
After the 1st character it can contain any letter, number, #,@,- or .
It's length must be at least 2, and no longer than 150. It cannot start with a space but can have a space in any position 2-150. (or 0-149 if you are thinking 0 based)

My test case is

```
9 Times
```

The full patter I am testing with is:

```
^[\dA-Za-z-.@#]{2,150}$
```

These cases work:

```
MichaelTest
9MichaelTest
#MichaelTest
@MichaelTest
```

Anything with a space is not working

Such as 9 Times

I am starting to see the issue is the space...how do I allow for a space, just not as the 1st character? (thanks TheGeneral for your tip)

Thanks!
M.

Comment: I am testing at https://regexr.com/ where I don't need to escape the . and the -. If I add the $ at the end ^[\dA-Za-z-.@#]$, it does not match on 9 times

Comment: What do you mean when you write this: "Starts with either a number or letter, # or @." It isn't clear where the # or @ come in to the requirement.

Comment: I edited my post to try and be more clear. The test case is not using the # or @. The issue though is when I try with 9 times. The first part ^[\dA-Za-z-.@#] works ok for other strings such as @9times. It fails with 9 times though.

Comment: Pro tip. For regex help, always put lots of test cases to show what will pass and fail, language is sometime hard to nail down what exactly you want especially if you aren't absolutely specific and defined. show us 10 things that will pass and a few that will fail. and you will probably have your question answered in seconds

Comment: I would suggest checking the overall input length and if it starts with a string separately from your expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z\d#@][a-zA-Z\d#@\-\. ]{1,149}$"
```

It's possible to build this with variables and string interpolation:

```
var start = @"a-zA-Z\d#@";
var then = start + @"\-\. ";
var regex = new Regex($@"[{start}][{then}]{{1,149}}");
```

### Test

Here is [a little program with which to test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g2SmhC).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var start = @"a-zA-Z\d#@";
        var then = start + @"\-\. ";
        var regex = new Regex($@"[{start}][{then}]{{1,149}}");
        Test(regex);
    }

    public static void Test(Regex regex)
    {
        const int numTests = 10;
        const int stringLength = 150;
        var rand = new Random();
        var start = new string[]{"1", "a", "#", "@", };
        var then = new string[]{"1", "a", "#", "@", "-", ".", " "};
        for (var i = 0; i < numTests; ++i)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder(start[0]);
            for (var j = 1; j < stringLength; ++j)
            {
                var r = rand.Next() % then.Length;
                builder.Append(then[r]);
            }

            var test = builder.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"{test} {regex.IsMatch(test)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is very nice. And I caught your point on the first answer I think because of the $ at the end.

Comment: After testing, this was the most correct for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try Regex: `^[\dA-Za-z@#][\dA-Za-z@#. -]{1,149}$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v1u30e/1)

Explanation:
First character will be any one of `\dA-Za-z@#`
followed by at least 1 to at max 149 chars of `\dA-Za-z@#. -`, bringing total chars to atleast 2 to at max 150.

Answer (score 0):

> it must start with a letter, number, # or @

That's this

```
^[A-Za-z0-9@#]
```

After that, you should check a pattern that can contain a space, any other of the listed characters character, up to the limit-1 (since you've already checked the one starting character), then anchor with `$`

```
[ A-Za-z0-9@#.-]{1,149}$
```

Then, stick those together

Comment: That passes for strings that are longer than 150 characters.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Might sharing an example? I added `$`, if that's what you mean

Comment: Yes. The `$` is what I meant.

Comment: Also, for C#.NET regular expressions, we need to escape the dash and period.